# SendGrid removing linebreaks in text email

Tags: javascript, node.js, sendgrid

I am testing my `Sendgrid` with a long text:

"Miusov, as a man man of breeding and deilcacy, could not but feel some  that despicable wretch, Fyodor Pavlovitch, too much to have been upset by

him in Father Zossima's cell, and so to have forgotten himself. "Teh monks  fall in with everything, I'll win them by politness, and show them that

I've nothing to do with that Aesop, thta buffoon, that Pierrot, and have merely been takken in over this affair, just as they have."

He determined to drop his litigation with the monastry".

However once i send the mail it turns out like this without line breaks:

[image]

So my question is what am i doing wrong?!

My code:

```
mymailer.sendTemplate = function (template_id, to, from, subject, keyReplacer, section, text, files, replyTo) {
    var email = new sendgrid.Email(),
        templateKey = templates[template_id];

    email.subject = subject;
    email.text = text;
    email.setFilters({
        "templates": {
            "settings": {
                "enable": 1,
                "template_id": templateKey
            }
        }
    });
    email.smtpapi.isHtml = true;
    email.smtpapi.header.sub = prepareSub(keyReplacer, section);
    email.smtpapi.header.section = prepareSection(section);
    email.files = prepareAttachement(files);
    sendgrid.send(email);
};

function prepareSection(section) {
    var finalObject = {};
    if (section) {
        _.forEach(section, function (value, key) {
            var k = '%' + key + '%';
            finalObject[k] = value;
        })
    }
    return finalObject;
}

function prepareSub(keyReplacer, section) {
    var finalObject = {};
    if (keyReplacer) {
        finalObject['firstname'] = keyReplacer;

        _.forEach(section, function (value, key) {
            finalObject[key] = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < keyReplacer.length; i++) {
                finalObject[key].push(value);
            }
        })
    }
    return finalObject;
}

function prepareAttachement(files) {
    var finalArray = [];
    if (files) {
        var i = 0;
        _.forEach(files, function (file) {
            finalArray.push({
                filename: file.file_name,
                contentType: file.file_type,
                cid: 'file-' + i,
                content: fs.readFileSync(file.path)
            });

            i++;
        });
    }
    return finalArray;
}
```

Comment: This is how it behaves for me too (although I use .net SmtpClient instead). I ended up setting IsHtml flag to true and using <br> and <p> tags. So my guess is that it's not really problem with sendgrid.

Comment: can you share your code?